# How to extract a paragraph from a pdf file and store its position?

Tags: pdfbox, pdf-extraction

I'm going to extract the content of a PDF file using PDFBox library. The content should be processed paragraph-by-paragraph and for each paragraph, I need its position for follow-up processing. Using the following code, I can extract the whole content of an input PDF:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
String txt = stripper.getText(doc);
doc.close();
```

I have two problems:

1. I don't know how to extract the content paragraph by paragraph.
2. I don't know how to store a position of a paragraph for follow-up processing (for example highlighting and etc.)

Thanks.

Comment: As @user3902842 already mentioned in his answer, PDF files in general do not know the concept of paragraphs. What you can do with PDFBox is extracting text letter by letter with positions (PDFBox can help you recognize text on the same line). Recognizing paragraphs in that extract would be your job.

Comment: I have reported this as an improvement at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4054

Comment: Have you solved your problem ? I am interested by the answer

Answer (score 0):

I use Poppler's command-line `pdftohtml` to extract rich-text but if you need paragraph clean then the PDF got to be a tagged-PDF. If you need the (x,y) co-ordinate of the paragraph then you need to dig deeper into Poppler. There is also Apache `PDFbox` Java library that can also be used. If you make an annotation in the beginning of the paragraph then you can pull out the annotation as an XML from the PDF where you will find the (x,y) co-ordinate of the annotation! Adobe puts a clever encryption into the PDF to make it undiscoverable, so it may not be easy (that's with all the legal hassles etc) to pull that out without Adobe tools.

Comment: I need the position of each paragraph to annotate it, if needed (for example: highlight it). When extracting the content of the input pdf file, I don't know the position of each paragraph. So, I can't make an annotation at the beginning and the end of paragraph. Each annotation needs "PDRectangle" and "QuadPoints" which have to be assigned using "PDAnnotationTextMarkup.setRectangle()" and "PDAnnotationTextMarkup.setQuadPoints()" functions.